# Duplicate Registration with Autofac

Tags: autofac, autofac-module

We are using Autofac builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly) method to scan for the modules and it works fine.  but  If a module is depends on the other modules , Then I am seeing duplicate registration happening because the dependent module is also registered separately  . Is there any way to avoid this duplication.

I am thinking of implementing IRegistrationSources assembly and try avoiding duplicate registration . Will that be a good ddea ?

Comment: What do you mean by module dependency ? could you share some code ?

Comment: Is there a problem with the duplicate registration? Only the last registration will be used.